# how to change filtered navigation list into a dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi all how can i change a list of attributes from filtered navigation into a dropdown menu?
Does not seem to be a standard option in the attributes field?

im using rwd template.
many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/layer/*` files

- `view.phtml` is used to list all the filter (attributes or categories) filterables. It includes `filter.phtml` for all filter.
- `filter.phtml` is used to render all the option of a filter
- `state.phtml` is used to render the active filters

You can change the DOM rendering of the layered filters in these files

Comment: Hi Pilou, thanks for this - any specific code to share?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do exactly.

Do you want filters to be rendered as dropdown ? Do you want filter options to be shown as dropdown ? How do you want your active filters to show, etc.

Comment: yes i want all the filter info to be as individual dropdowns